# NGINX - rewrite rule with regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an url ex. `www.something.com/cdn/util/sacle/180/180/......` I need to rewrite it to the `www.something.com/cdn/_util/scale.php/180/180....` How can I do it in nginx? My solution now:

```
location /cdn/ {
  rewrite ^/util/scale(.*)$ /_util/scale.php/$1 break;
}
```

But it is not a good solution for me, because I have some other rewrite rule:

```
location /serve {
rewrite ^/serve(.*)$ /_util/serve.php/$1 break;
}
location /upload {
rewrite ^/upload(.*)$ /_util/upload.php/$1 break;
}
location /delete {
rewrite ^/delete(.*)$ /_util/delete.php/$1 break;
}
location /copy {
rewrite ^/copy(.*)$ /_util/copy.php/$1 break;
}
location /move {
rewrite ^/move(.*)$ /_util/move.php/$1 break;
}
location /util {
rewrite ^/util/placeholder(.*)$ /_util/placeholder.php/$1 break;
rewrite ^/util/thumb(.*)$ /_util/thumb.php/$1 break;
rewrite ^/util/scale(.*)$ /_util/scale.php/$1 break;
rewrite ^/util/marker(.*)$ /_util/marker.php/$1 break;
}
```

I think it is possible in one line too. And the php got the parameters from the url. Which is now working, if I write the url like this:

```
http://cdn-staging.something.com/util/scale/180/180/dev-employer-images/iamge.jpg
```

It is create this:

```
http://cdn-staging.something.com/_util/scale.php/180/180/dev-employer-images/iamge.jpg
```

But it is under Apache, and I need to make it to nginx.

Comment: You could see that all you current rules have the same prefix in `location` and `rewrite`. And that's for reason. BTW, `break` flag is somewhat strange here, I guess It should be `last`.

Comment: Yes it's true, thank you.